# Please rename ng2-bootstrap tag to ngx-bootstrap

Tags: support, tags

I am the maintainer of [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) (it was called [ng2-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap)  half a year ago). Even after half of a year, and deprecation tag on ng2-bootstrap, it has 70k downloads per month :(

Please help me to remove mentions of ng2-* version to reduce confusion about it, by renaming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng2-bootstrap
tag into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngx-bootstrap

Or close the tag, if renaming is not feasible.

Comment: can you confirm that the solutions to ng2- will work for ngx- too

Comment: Is ngx2-bootstrap 100% backwards-compatible with ng2-bootstrap? If not, then they are separate versions and two different tags are appropriate.

Comment: It appears to be the exact same library just renamed.  The ng2 page contains the same information and links to the exact same links as the ngx page (urls which contain variations of "ngx" in them).

Comment: ngx-bootstrap has same versions as ng2-bootstrap,
unfortunately I can not remove old npm package